# How to conditionally render and hide multiple components onClick in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

**My Class Component houses 4 different buttons.** Ideally when the user presses one of those buttons an Accordion Element corresponding to that button should render. **Like if someone presses the summary button the summaryAccordion will render etc.**

*The problem is I don't know how to render only that component based on the button click.*

If the user presses the summary button the summaryAccordion will render, but if the user presses the rates button after the summary button, the summary accordion should hide itself then the ratesAccordion should render. This same logic should be carried to all four buttons.

**Below is my attempt at solving this:**

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rendersummaryAccordions: false,
            renderservicesAccordions: false,
            rendertravelAccordions: false, 
            renderratesAccordions: false, 

            isSummaryAccordionActive: false, 
            isServicesAccordionActive: false, 
            isTravelAccordionActive: false, 
            isRatesAccordionActive: false, 


        };


    }

        // The Summary Button onClick calls this function to set the state of the summaryAccordionDetector variable
        setStateifSummaryAccordionsActive = () => {
            this.setState({isSummaryAccordionActive: true})
            console.log(this.state.isSummaryAccordionActive)
            this.callSummaryAccordionsLogicGate();
            console.log("setStateisSummaryAccordionsActive Was called")
        }

        //Then the function above  calls this function that checks if the summaryAccordionDetector variable is really true 
        callSummaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
            if (this.state.isSummaryAccordionActive) {
                console.log("callSummaryAccordionsLogicGate found that theSummaryAccordion is active")
               this.summaryAccordionsLogicGate();

            }
            else {
                console.log("callSummaryAccordionsLogicGate found that the summary accordion wasn't active")
            }
        }

        //If the function above verifies that the summaryAccordionDetector is really true it calls this function which renders the summary accordion
           summaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
                this.setState({rendersummaryAccordions: true});
                console.log("summaryAccordionsLogicGate was called, render the summary accordion")
        } 


        // The Services onClick calls this function to set the state of the servicesAccordionDetector variable
        setStateifServicesAccordionsActive = () => {
            this.setState({isServicesAccordionActive: true})
            console.log(this.state.isServicesAccordionActive)
            this.callServicesAccordionsLogicGate();
            console.log("setStateisServicesAccordionsActive Was called")
        }

        //Then the function above  calls this function that checks if the summaryAccordionDetector variable is really true 
        callServicesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
            if (this.state.isServicesAccordionActive) {
                console.log("callServicesAccordionsLogicGate found that theSummaryAccordion is active")
               this.servicesAccordionsLogicGate();

            }
            else {
                console.log("callServicesAccordionsLogicGate found that the summary accordion wasn't active")
            }
        }

        //If the function above verifies that the summaryAccordionDetector is really true it calls this function which renders the summary accordion
        servicesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
            this.setState({renderservicesAccordions: true});
            console.log("servicesAccordionsLogicGate was called, render the services accordion")
    } 



        render() {
//PlaceHolder Variables for the Accordions
            let summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = null
            let servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = null
            let ratesAccordionPlaceHolder = null
            let travelAccordionPlaceHolder = null

//If renderSummaryAccordions is true and renderServicesAccordions is false then set a variable equal to the summaryAccordion Element so that it can render
            this.state.rendersummaryAccordions && this.state.renderservicesAccordions === false ? summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = <SummaryAccordions/> : summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = null;
            this.state.renderservicesAccordions && this.state.rendersummaryAccordions === false ? servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = <ServicesAccordions/> : servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = null;


            return (
                <div>
                    <center>
                        <table cellspacing="30px">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="SUMMARY" icon="pi pi-home" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.setStateifSummaryAccordionsActive} style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="SERVICES" icon="pi pi-users" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.setStateifServicesAccordionsActive} style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="TRAVEL" icon="pi pi-cloud" className="TabMenuButtons"  style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="RATES" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons" style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                    <tr>

                        {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br />
{/* Render the placeHolder Elements here */}
                {ratesAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {servicesAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {travelAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {summaryAccordionPlaceHolder}
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
```

**I am new to React any help is appreciated**

**EDIT 1:**

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        renderSummaryAccordion: false,
        renderServicesAccordion: false,
        renderTravelAccordion: false, 
        renderRatesAccordion: false

        };


    }





        render() {


            return (
                <div>
                    <center>
                        <table cellspacing="30px">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="SUMMARY" icon="pi pi-home" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={()=> this.setState({renderSummaryAccordion : !this.state.renderSummaryAccordion})} style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="SERVICES" icon="pi pi-users" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={()=> this.setState({renderServicesAccordion : !this.state.renderServicesAccordion})} style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="TRAVEL" icon="pi pi-cloud" className="TabMenuButtons"  style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button label="RATES" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons" style={{ marginRight: '.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                    <tr>

                        {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                        <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br />
{this.state.renderSummaryAccordion && <SummaryAccordions/>}
{this.state.renderServicesAccordion && <ServicesAccordions/>}
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bind the button click to a state's property (usually a boolean) and use [conditional render](http://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render only those components that should be displayed:

```
render(){
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({condition1 : !this.state.condition1})}> Toggle BUtton 1 </button>
            <tr>
                 {condition1 && <td>foo</td>}
                 {condition2 && <td>foo</td>}
            </tr>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by bind the button-click to a state property. Like bind this in the function?

Comment: No. Just have a property in your state which get's toggled everytime a button is clicked

Comment: In your example what is the && saying in your <tr>? If condition 1 is true &&?

Comment: If condition1 is `true` then render this `td`

Comment: I've tried react docs way of condtional rendering but there example uses one central button while mine has 4. I'm confused on how to make the transition

Comment: One way would be to have 4 properties (one for each button) and toggled each one based on it's button click.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting it, so your setting the state to it's opposite in the button's Onclick (in this case setting the bool to false).  And then below saying if condition 1 is true render component 1. Then I'd  just have to do this for the other three buttons

Comment: Exactly! There are less verbose solutions, but this will work just fine in this case

Comment: Nice! The good news is, I implemented your methods and it works! The bad news is, when I click on one button an accordion renders. When I click on other buttons right after, each component that the button is supposed to render, renders on top of each other. For instance, if I click the summary button I get an summary accordion, if I click the services button right after I get the summary and services accordion. Is there any way around this. Above is my code

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out just verified your answer